# QnetworkReply error - Symbian Qt

Tags: qt, symbian, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have the following piece of code.

```
  QNetworkAccessManager *man = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QNetworkRequest getRequest;
    getRequest.setUrl((QUrl)requestUrl);

    m_svcReply = man->get(getRequest);
    connect(m_svcReply, SIGNAL(finished()),this, SLOT(getWebRequestFinished()));
    connect(m_svcReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),this, SLOT(webrequestFailed(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

If I'm executing this request over **WIFI**, I get a proper response from the server.
However if I'm executing this request over **3G**, I get a **protocol "" is unknown** error.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the [NetworkServices capability](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/NetworkServices) to your app?

> NetworkServices is a Symbian
>   capability which grants access to
>   remote services (such as dialing a
>   number or sending a text message,
>   WLAN, GPRS), **which might incur a cost
>   for the mobile device user.**

Comment: I've added the following capabilities - symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY = NetworkServices \
    LocalServices \
    ReadUserData \
    WriteUserData \
    UserEnvironment \
    ReadDeviceData \
    WriteDeviceData

Comment: The request actually works via WIFI.. but does not via 3G.. but I can access websites via 3G using the default browser.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to use 3G ?